# Создание pattern для regex python 3

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Как написать pattern для regex, к примеру, я знаю начало строки и конец, но не знаю количество символов между ними, допустим начинается на 07 а знаю что заканчивается на 4. Если я пропишу `_pattern = r'07(...)4+'` , то найдет только те значения, где между 7 и 4 3 символа.

Подскажите как сделать чтобы находил все слова, где между 7 и 4 неизвестное количество непробельных символов?

Comment: Непробельный символ - `\S`, квантификаторы - `*` - любое кол-во, `+` - любое >0, `?` - 0 или 1 символ, `{3,5}` - от 3 до 5 символов. Вам нужно `r'07(\S*)4'`.

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно

Comment: @andy.37 оформите это как ответ, пожалуйста

Comment: Как отметить Ваше сообщение, что это ответ. Не до конца еще разобрался с сайтом

Comment: @vadimaid: Вообще-то, не совсем понятно, что вам нужно: найти в тексте "слова" типа `070a^04` и нужно найти все совпадения или же у вас есть строки такого типа, которые нужно проверить на валидность? Лучше всего добавить в вопрос конкретный пример кода с входным текстом и пояснить, что нужно получить в результате.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непробельный символ - `\S`, квантификаторы (сколько символов должно быть в искомой строке): `*` - любое количество (включая 0), `+` - любое количество больше 0, `?` - 0 или 1 символ (иначе говоря символ либо есть 1, либо его нет), `{3,5}` - от 3 до 5 символов.

Итоговая регулярка: `r'07(\S*)4'`.

Однако более правильно в контексте задачи, использовать `look-ahead` и `look-behind`:

`r'(?<=07)\S*(?=4)'`, тогда регулярка будет целиком находить то, что находится между `07` и `4`.